# Numerical characteristics of a Riemann surface of function

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

Let $f(x)$ be an analytic function in $\mathbb{C}\setminus A$, where $A$ is a discrete finite set of branch points. I have some questions.

1. Given a set of values of $f(x)$ is some domain $U \subset \mathbb{C}$ is it possible to say without performing analytic continuation how many branch points are in $\overline{\mathbb{C}} \setminus \overline{U}$ or do they exist at all? Is there some formula?
2. I have the same question about total index of branch points lying outside $U$.
3. Is there a way to compute a genus of Riemann surface of function $f(x)$ given its values only in the domain $U$? If the answer to second question is positive then it can be done via Riemann-Hurwitz formula 
   $$
   \text{(genus)} = \frac{1}{2}\text{(total index)}-\text{(number of sheets)}+1.
   $$